# Service call failed in json-prolog while querying an owl file in Cram

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob, roslisp, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I started a roslisp node in cram and have json-prolog query services (i can see

```
/json_prolog/finish
/json_prolog/next_solution
/json_prolog/query
/json_prolog/simple_query
```

when i do "rosservice list").

Also by typing (json-prolog:check-connection) i receive T. so i assume that everything set up properly.

problem is when i try any query like

```
(json-prolog:prolog '("rdf_has" ?owlname "http://knowrob.org/kb/srdl2-comp.owl#urdfName" ("literal" ?var)))
```

i receive

```
Prolog query failed: Got error: The value
             |'["rdf_has",{"variable":"OWLNAME"},"http://knowrob.org/kb/srdl2-comp.owl#urdfName",{"term":["literal",{"variable":"VAR"}]}]'|
           is not of type
             LIST..
```

also i have

```
[(JSON-PROLOG) WARN] 1505226166.532: Service call failed. 
[(JSON-PROLOG) WARN] 1505226166.532: Retrying...
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270835/service-call-failed-in-json-prolog-while-querying-an-owl-file-in-cram/) by [aAsoodeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31814/aasoodeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This seems like an error on the KnowRob side. I execute it on my machine and it works fine.
I'm using the master branch of KnowRob (on 14.04), the latest commit I have is from 3rd of September.
And I'm using the latest version of cram_json_prolog, master branch, last commit was on 26 June.
Try `prolog-simple` or a simpler query in general.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aAsoodeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31814/aasoodeh/) on 2017-09-13**:
same error when trying prolog-simple. do you know any cram project that i can use as pattern to build a clear project? any tutorial?   Thanks

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2017-09-18**:
We have a bunch of tutorials.
Here is he [one that showcases most complex behaviors](/cram-system.org/tutorials/advanced/bullet_world)
It runs on the newest CRAM version (0.4.0).
Consult the installation page to get the latest version.